# aws-amplify/cli is acting weird

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am an intern at my company, I just need to wrap a few things up before I leave.
One of the problems I'm having is 
AWS Cognito, specifically AWS Amplify CLI.
My laptop

```
amplify --version
```

returns 4.17.1

This is ideal. 
The office computer is showing me 3.10.0
This is nowhere near ideal since especially when I do

```
amplify push
```

the following errors pops up:

```
Resource Name: UserPoolClientLambda (AWS::Lambda::Function)
Event Type: create
Reason: The runtime parameter of nodejs8.10 is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. We recommend you use the new runtime (nodejs12.x) while creating or updating functions. (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: f6d965b6-e4a6-4a0e-a380-fc07ac950266)
```

I have tried the following

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
```

I've tried

```
npm uninstall -g @aws-ampify/cli
```

restart computer  then

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
```

The `amplify --version`
hasn't changed from the old 3.10.0

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error myself, but there is a fast solution to it which is not obvious to the AWS novices as myself.

Apparently there can be a console image running an outdated version of the CLI.
To fix, do as follows:

1. Go to build settings
2. Scroll to bottom, to Build Image Settings
3. Click `[Edit]`-button
4. Click  `[Add package version override]`
5. Choose `Amplify CLI`, version latest, and `[Save]`

The end result should look like this:
[image: Build image settings]

Then just trigger another build, which takes a couple of minutes. The build takes longer the first time after adding to the backend, such as after adding api or auth, but will be a bit faster in your future builds

*Credit goes to @jimtheplant on `AWS Amplify` Discord community who helped me with this issue*

Comment: I've performed both of these actions, but still get an old version (4.27.3) of the cli whenever I run "amplify version". My global cli package.json in "..\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli" shows the latest version (4.32.0). I can't find any reference to the old version. But if I run the version command anywhere, I get the old version returned.

Anybody have any other suggestions? I'm running on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by going into `~/.npm/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli` and running `node scripts/post-install.js` myself.

I'm not sure if that's the intended behaviour or if it's a bug, but I've asked here https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3149#issuecomment-665720866